# {Symbol.toStringTag} not working for Error object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, es6-class

For a starting reference point, I read the following:

• Customizing ES6 via well-known symbols

• http://2ality.com/2015/09/well-known-symbols-es6.html

> ... and based on the examples/code above & the section:
>
> ○ Default toString tags
>
> ○
>   http://2ality.com/2015/09/well-known-symbols-es6.html#default-tostring-tags

... I would expect that one or both the following approaches would allow me override the behavior of the "Error Object" when it's used in "`console.log(returnVal)`" for instance:

```
console.log("Approach #1");
class CoolError extends Error {
  constructor (args) {
    super(args);
  }
  [Symbol.toPrimitive] (hint) {
    return "*************" + this.name + " : " + this.message;
    // note: I shouldn't need this, however, it doesn't work either...
  }
  [Symbol.toStringTag] (hint) {
    return ">>>>>>>>>>>>>" + this.name + " : " + this.message;
  }
}
returnVal = new CoolError("errMsg");
console.log("returnVal[Symbol.toPrimitive] === " + returnVal[Symbol.toPrimitive]);
console.log(" ");
console.log(returnVal);

console.log(">");
console.log(" >");
console.log("  >");
console.log("   >");

console.log("Approach #2");
returnVal = new Error("errMsg");
console.log("returnVal[Symbol.toStringTag] === " + returnVal[Symbol.toStringTag]);
returnVal[Symbol.toStringTag] = function (hint) {return "*************" + this.name + " : " + this.message};
console.log("returnVal[Symbol.toStringTag] === " + returnVal[Symbol.toStringTag]);
console.log(" ");
console.log(returnVal);
```

... ... however, no such luck...  in both cases, the console.log(returnVal) statements return the entire Error stack trace (which is what I'm trying to prevent).

I would like to point out that I can successfully "set" the behaviors of a custom object:

So I know the general approach 'works', I just can't seem to make it work with regards to the built in Error object.

```
class AnswerToLifeAndUniverseAndEverything {

    [Symbol.toPrimitive] (hint) {
        console.log(typeof hint);
        console.log(hint);
        if (hint === 'string') {
            console.log('string');
            return 'Like, 42, man';
        } else if (hint === 'number') {
            console.log('number');
            return 42;
        } else {
            console.log('default');
            // when pushed, most classes (except Date) default to returning a number primitive
            return 42;
        }
    }
}

var answer = new AnswerToLifeAndUniverseAndEverything();

console.log(  Number(answer) + " === 42");
console.log(  String(answer) + " === 'Like, 42, man'");
```

(Also, I'd like for it to work using both attempt approaches #1 & #2 above, if possible.)

***Any ideas?***

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding a few main things.

> I would expect that one or both the following approaches would allow me override the behavior of the "Error Object" when it's used in "console.log(returnVal)" for instance:

`console.log` has no official spec for how it will display an object. To my knowledge, none of the current implementations use `toString`. Node specifically allows objects to have a `.inspect` function to return a value to render, but that's about it.

Second, you appear to be misunderstanding what `toStringTag` is for. `toStringTag` is specifically a *tag* string value. It is not a function, which is why your function isn't doing anything. A `toStringTag` usage might look like

```
var obj = {};
obj.toString(); // [object Object]
obj[Symbol.toStringTag] = "MyCustomThing";
obj.toString(); // [object MyCustomThing]
```

and that's it. It's a simple string value for use with the *default* implementation of `.toString()` on an object.

Given what you're looking for, your solution would be overriding `Symbol.toPrimitive`, or more easily probably just overriding `.toString` since that will have exactly the same behavior in this case. Then when you log your object, just convert it to a string first, just like you're doing in `AnswerToLifeAndUniverseAndEverything`.

```
class CoolError extends Error {
  constructor (args) {
    super(args);
  }
  toString() {
    return "*************" + this.name + " : " + this.message;
  }
}
var returnVal = new CoolError("errMsg");

console.log("" + returnVal)
// *************Error : errMsg
```